# Auto Bottom Scroll in reactjs and jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have integrated dialogflow in a react page and it is working now the issue is whenever I am writing a phrase in the bot is responding but the chat window is not getting auto scrolled to bottom. I want the bot window to be automatically scrolled to bottom every time.

```
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        const { feed, sendMessage } = this.props;// structure of the bot
        return (
          <div // which is the main div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "green",
              height: "70%",
              width: "23%",
              position: "fixed",
              bottom: 0,
              right: 5
            }}
          >
            <div // inner div
              style={{
                height: "67%",
                width: "22%",
                position: "fixed",
                bottom: "30px",
                maxHeight: "65%",
                right: "5px",
                overflowY: "scroll",
                overflowX: "hidden"
              }}
            >
              <h1>CHATBOT!</h1>

              {feed.map(entry => ( // the div where the user is typing the response
                <div>{entry.text}</div> // inner- inner div
              ))}
            </div>
            <div
              style={{
                position: "fixed",
                right: "23%",
                bottom: "28px",
                marginLeft: "-1300px"
              }}
            >
              <input
                style={{
                  position: "fixed",
                  width: "22%",
                  height: "3%"
                }}
                type="text" // the value by which the user is connected the bot
                onKeyDown={e => // this is the box where the response is coming from the bot
                  e.keyCode === 13 ? sendMessage(e.target.value) : null
                }// 13 is the ascii of ENTER
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      feed: state
    });



    chat.js // intergration with dialogflow 


    const accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //you have to enter your key
    const client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken });

    const ON_MESSAGE = "ON_MESSAGE";

    export const sendMessage = (text, sender = "user") => ({ // bot text box
      type: ON_MESSAGE,
      payload: { text, sender }
    });

    const messageMiddleware = () => next => action => {
      next(action);

      if (action.type === ON_MESSAGE) {
        const { text } = action.payload;
        client.textRequest(text).then(onSuccess);

        function onSuccess(response) {// response from dialgflow
          const {
            result: { fulfillment }
          } = response;
          next(sendMessage(fulfillment.speech, "bot"));
        }
      }
    };

    const initState = [{ text: "" }];
    const messageReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ON_MESSAGE:
          return [...state, action.payload];

        default:
          return state;
      }
    };




    app.js

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        const { feed, sendMessage } = this.props;// structure of the bot
        return (
          <div // which is the main div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "green",
              height: "70%",
              width: "23%",
              position: "fixed",
              bottom: 0,
              right: 5
            }}
          >
            <div // inner div
              style={{
                height: "67%",
                width: "22%",
                position: "fixed",
                bottom: "30px",
                maxHeight: "65%",
                right: "5px",
                overflowY: "scroll",
                overflowX: "hidden"
              }}
            >
              <h1>CHATBOT!</h1>

              {feed.map(entry => ( // the div where the user is typing the response
                <div>{entry.text}</div> // inner- inner div
              ))}
            </div>
            <div
              style={{
                position: "fixed",
                right: "23%",
                bottom: "28px",
                marginLeft: "-1300px"
              }}
            >
              <input
                style={{
                  position: "fixed",
                  width: "22%",
                  height: "3%"
                }}
                type="text" // the value by which the user is connected the bot
                onKeyDown={e => // this is the box where the response is coming from the bot
                  e.keyCode === 13 ? sendMessage(e.target.value) : null
                }// 13 is the ascii of ENTER
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      feed: state
    });
```

I want the bot window to be automatically scrolled whenever I type anything in the window.

Comment: Hi Thomas, just wrote you a solution, please let me know if it helps! And if it does work, please consider marking it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

In the App component, you can create a span or div and place it right below the chat-feed.

Then give that element a `ref`, which we will use to scroll to upon receiving any new message.

You can use `React.createRef()` to make that `ref`. Refs essentially give us access to methods you traditionally see in vanilla JavaScript.

It also looks like you're receiving updated messages via props from Redux. So we can use `componentDidUpdate()` to run some logic that will scroll to that ref element.

```
class App extends Component {

  endOfFeed = React.createRef()

  scrollToEnd = () => {
      if(this.endOfFeed.current){
          this.endOfFeed.current.scrollIntoView()
      }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(prevProps.feed.length !== this.props.feed.length){
         this.scrollToEnd()
     }
  }

  render() {
    const { feed, sendMessage } = this.props;// structure of the bot
    return (
      <div // which is the main div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "green",
          height: "70%",
          width: "23%",
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 0,
          right: 5
        }}
      >
        <div // inner div
          style={{
            height: "67%",
            width: "22%",
            position: "fixed",
            bottom: "30px",
            maxHeight: "65%",
            right: "5px",
            overflowY: "scroll",
            overflowX: "hidden"
          }}
        >
          <h1>CHATBOT!</h1>

          {feed.map(entry => ( // the div where the user is typing the response
            <div>{entry.text}</div> // inner- inner div
          ))}

          <span ref={this.endOfFeed}></span>

        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            right: "23%",
            bottom: "28px",
            marginLeft: "-1300px"
          }}
        >
          <input
            style={{
              position: "fixed",
              width: "22%",
              height: "3%"
            }}
            type="text" // the value by which the user is connected the bot
            onKeyDown={e => // this is the box where the response is coming from the bot
              e.keyCode === 13 ? sendMessage(e.target.value) : null
            }// 13 is the ascii of ENTER
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  feed: state
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.scrollY property and give offset accordingly.
Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY